# NullPointerException while trying to read JSON and trying to convert it to a POJO (deserialization)

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, pojo

Our goal is to: parse a json file and deserialize it into a java POJO

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
16:39:21,628 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.NullPointerException
16:39:21,628 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.webservice_child.war //ProfileDeserializer.deserialize(ProfileDeserializer.java:31)
16:39:21,628 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.webservice_child.war //ProfileDeserializer.deserialize(ProfileDeserializer.java:16)
```

The files we are trying to parse look like this:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "anon": {
      "/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname": true,
      "/brief/versicherungsnehmer/nachname": true
    }
  }
}
```

Our Json Parser class called `JSONMuncher` looks like this:

```java
public class JSONMuncher {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JSONMuncher() {
        this.objectMapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        return objectMapper;
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
                .addSerializer(Properties.class, new ProfileSerializer())
                .addDeserializer(Properties.class, new ProfileDeserializer());

        return new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory()
                .disable(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_JSON_CONTENT))
                .registerModule(module);
    }
    public Object readConfig(String filepath) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper();
            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
            mapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            // do not serialize null value fields
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
            module.addSerializer(Properties.class, new ProfileSerializer());
            module.addDeserializer(Properties.class, new ProfileDeserializer());
            mapper.registerModule(module);

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            System.out.println("[DEBUG!!!!!!!!!111!!!]: " + is.read());
            Properties anon = mapper.readValue(is, Properties.class);
            
            System.out.println(anon.getVorname());
            System.out.println(anon.getNachname());

            return anon;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Beep Boop Err!!! ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is our ProfileSerializer Class:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProfileSerializer extends StdSerializer<Properties> {

    public ProfileSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ProfileSerializer(Class<Properties> src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Properties property, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();

        if (property != null) {
            gen.writeObjectField("vorname", property.getVorname());
            gen.writeObjectField("nachname", property.getNachname());
        }

        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

This is our ProfileDeserializer Class:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;

@JsonDeserialize(using = Properties.class)
public class ProfileDeserializer extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer<Properties> {

    public ProfileDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ProfileDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Properties deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode profileNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        Properties property = new Properties();
        property.setVorname(profileNode.get("vorname").booleanValue());
        property.setNachname(profileNode.get("nachname").booleanValue());
        //property.un

        return property;
    }

}
```

And this is the `Properties` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
//import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;


public class Properties extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer<Properties> {
    private boolean vorname;
    private boolean nachname;

    public void setVorname(boolean vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public void setNachname(boolean nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public boolean getVorname() {
        return this.vorname;
    }

    public boolean getNachname() {
        return this.nachname;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @JsonProperty("anon")
    private void unpackNested(Map<Boolean, Object> anon) {
        //this.vorname = (boolean) anon.get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname");
        //this.nachname = (boolean) anon.get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/nachname");
        Map<Boolean,Boolean> vorname = (Map<Boolean,Boolean>) anon.get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname");
        Map<Boolean,Boolean> nachname = (Map<Boolean,Boolean>) anon.get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/nachname");

        this.vorname = (boolean) vorname.get("vorname");
        this.nachname = (boolean) nachname.get("nachname");
        //Map<Boolean,Boolean> owner = (Map<Boolean,Boolean>)anon.get("owner");
        //this.ownerName = owner.get("name");
    }

    @Override
    public Properties deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode profileNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        Properties property = new Properties();
        property.setVorname(profileNode.get("vorname").booleanValue());
        property.setNachname(profileNode.get("nachname").booleanValue());
        //property.un

        return property;
    }

    /*@Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return null;
    }*/
}
```

The `Properties` class is used to store the json values in POJOs.

We tried:

- changing the inherited class type of the class Properties
- changing the vendor for fasterxml from `codehaus` to `fasterxml` because all of the examples used fasterxml.
- changing the line `this.vorname = (boolean) anon.get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname");` to `Map<Boolean,Boolean> vorname = (Map<Boolean,Boolean>) anon.get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname");`
- adding `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);` to the mapper config to prevent NullPointers
- changing `StdSerializer` to `JsonSerializer`

Edit: I just tried out printing all the fields inside profileNode and it looks like the nodes that should exist because they exist in the json are in fact not present:

```
09:22:07,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Child nodes: dokumenttyp
09:22:07,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Child nodes: sprache
09:22:07,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Child nodes: vertragsdaten
09:22:07,064 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Child nodes: sachbearbeiter
09:22:07,064 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Child nodes: versicherungsnehmer
09:22:07,064 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Child nodes: bankverbindung
09:22:07,064 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Child nodes: person
```

Comment: seem like profileNode.get("vorname") returns null and causes the NPE bevause the property is "/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname" and not "vorname"

Comment: @aeberhart please see the print out of all the elements inside profileNode. It looks like those child nodes really do not exist. However in the json file the values are there. How can I get these values correctly from the json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I was able to fix this issue and getting the correct values by modifying my deserialize() function like this:

```java
@Override
    public Properties deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
       JsonNode profileNode = 
          jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
       Properties property = new Properties();
        
   System.out.println(profileNode.get("properties").get("anon").get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname").booleanValue());
        property.setVorname(profileNode.get("properties").get("anon").get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/vorname").booleanValue());

 System.out.println(profileNode.get("properties").get("anon").get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/nachname").booleanValue());
        property.setNachname(profileNode.get("properties").get("anon").get("/brief/versicherungsnehmer/nachname").booleanValue());

return property;

}
```